# Does a HttpServlet have to respond to a request?

Tags: java, servlets

I have several servlets that do things server side. On a few I just encode some unnecessary data and send it back, which seems pointless. Do you have to respond ? What happens when you just say `return` ? I've done that before and nothing seems to go wrong but I am relatively new to servlets. Are there consequences for simply returning that go above my head ? And what exactly happens when you return;

```
if(request.getParameter("name").equals("saveusedcards")) {
        String sessId = request.getSession().getId();
        //encode request with confirmation that cards were successfully updated
        if(usersUpdatedCards.get(sessId).isEmpty()){
            //no cards were seen

        }
        boolean success = DataDAO.updateCards(usersUpdatedCards.get(sessId));

        if(success){
            System.out.println("Data base update successfull!");
            String responseMessage = new Gson().toJson("card successfully udpated");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("updated cards response message: "+responseMessage);
            response.getWriter().write(responseMessage);
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data base update failed...");
            String responseMessage = new Gson().toJson("card was not successfully updated");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("updated cards response message: "+responseMessage);
            response.getWriter().write(responseMessage);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If those classes do not respond to HTTP requests, then they shouldn't be Servlets in the first place

Comment: Do you have to respond, yes but it can be without content. You should at least return a response code to the client (probably a 200 or 201 depending on what you want to communicate). You don't have to return content but something indicating that it went OK would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet must produce an HTTP response for the client, however it is perfectly acceptable to return no content in the response body.  When doing so your servlet should make this clear to the client by sending a response code of 204 (no content).  Reference: https://httpstatuses.com/204

Here is an example of how you would set the response code from the `doGet` method.  You could do the same from `doPost` or `service` methods.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Do whatever work you need to do here...

    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse. SC_NO_CONTENT);  // This returns a 204
}
```

Comment: Ok that looks good, so its best to indicate that their is no content. Here would you have to manually send the response or when you return does a response automatically get sent regardless of what you encode ?

Comment: If you do not set the response code in your servlet, the container will pick a value for you.  I'd have to read the servlet spec to see exactly what it would pick, but my best guess is 200-ok.  It is far better however for your servlet to be explicit about this and to generate the response code itself, so that there is no question.